# jQuery.post gives error

Tags: html, ajax, jquery

I am trying to get this code to work but it gives me an error. It doesn't seem to execute.

```
jQuery.post("getResults.php", {id:id} , function(data)
        {
            jQuery("select#kDate").removeAttr("disabled");
            jQuery("select#kDate").html(data);
        })
        .success(function() { alert("second success"); })
        .error(function() { alert("error"); })
        .complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
     });
```

Any help would be appreciated.

Comment: You don't need 2 success functions..

Comment: I just found that code on here and added it to try and work out what's going on with my code.

Comment: Find out more about the error by logging the passed arguments in the error function. Also: What does Firebug say?

Comment: You can see everything inside error function by doing `console.log(arguments)` if you're using Chrome Developer.. Then you can browse through them

Comment: "It gives me an error" is not very specific.

Comment: I didn't know what error it was giving as I couldn't find out

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The error function has 3 parameters....

```
 error(jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown)
```

try this:

```
error(function(xhr, status, detail) { alert("error ("+status+") : " + detail); });
```

docs are here: http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.ajax/

Comment: this just gives me error: error

Comment: @bobthemac - try the new version

Comment: I have run this and get the error not found

Comment: @bobthemac - that means it can't find the URL -- try a fully qualified URL

Answer (score 0):

Try this : you can see [here](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery.post/) also.

```
var id = "some-value";
jQuery.post("getResults.php?id="+id, function(data) {
  jQuery("select#kDate").removeAttr("disabled");
  jQuery("select#kDate").html(data);
})
.success(function() { alert("second success"); })
.error(function() { alert("error"); })
.complete(function() { alert("complete"); });
```